# How to get mean/median of real eastate data along time series in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have real estate data (monthly house retail data) and I want to get annual house sale for each region along time series. It's not intuitive for me how to get mean/median for time series data. Is there anyone point me out how to do this?

Here is how my time series data looks like:

Plus, here I shared example dataset with online filesharing host: [example data snippet](https://filebin.net/u23rzi0daic691qh)

**data description**:

in this real estate data, the row is regions, columns is monthly house retail statistics. I want to get an annual mean/median of this real estate data. How can I make this happen? any idea?
[image]

**desired output**:

here is sketch desired output that I want to get.

```
region                              2012_mean 2012_median 2013_mean 2013_median

Chicago, IL metro area                  xxx     xxx         xxx         xxx
Chicago, IL                             xxx     xxx         xxx         xxx
Chicago, IL - Albany Park               xxx     xxx         xxx         xxx
Chicago, IL - Andersonville             xxx     xxx         xxx         xxx
Chicago, IL - Arcadia Terrace           xxx     xxx         xxx         xxx
```

Comment: Where is your attempt at coding it though? Seems to me you need to google [means in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) and [medians in pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.median.html), make an attempt yourself and then come back with a more direct question about how the documentation across the internet is insufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure your columns is `datetime` object , the do with `groupby`

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.strip()
df=df.set_index('Region')
s=df.T.groupby(df.columns.year).agg(['mean','median']).T.unstack()
s.columns=s.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I got ``AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'year'. Would you mind to try example data snippets?

Comment: @Jerry df.set_index(`region`,inplace=True);df.columns=pd.to_datetime(df.columns);

Comment: @Jerry did you run `df.set_index('region',inplace=True)`

Comment: I am having this error after I tried your solution: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`, why is that? Thank you for your help

Comment: @Jerry run this line `df.set_index('Region',inplace=True);df.columns=pd.to_datetime(df.columns);`

Comment: would you mind to try example data snippets? Thank for your nice solution, appreciated.

Comment: @Jerry that is picture dose not address your current problem

Comment: I think your solution should work but have strange error, why? would you mind to try this [example data snippet](https://jmp.sh/v/moy2M0FrjE5zmVVsczJY) ? Thank you again.

Comment: @Jerry what is the error ? I tried the code with the data works fine

Comment: I have this error: `ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'Region')`, it's strange, how to get rid of this error?

Comment: I am so sorry, I have error again `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')`.

Comment: @Jerry df.columns=df.columns.astype(str)

Comment: all code works except this line `s.columns=s.columns.map('_'.join)` which gives me this error: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`. any further solution? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jerry `s.columns = s.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)`

Comment: How can I index column while using `Region` as a column that I can use it for joining another dataframe?

Comment: @Jerry df.reset_index(inplace=True)